# Laravel Dusk running two browsers in parallel

Tags: laravel, automation, race-condition, laravel-dusk

I want to test two browsers running at the same time and making a purchase of the same one product. (One browser should be successful and the other to come back with an error message)

I tried using two instances of the `Browser` class like this:

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $first, Browser $second) {
    $first->visit('/');
    $second->visit('/');
    $first->click('.btn.purchase');
    $second->click('.btn.purchase');
}
```

The problem is that they are not running in parallel. I clearly see that the first one clicks and waits a bit then the second clicks. It is as if it has to wait for the click to take action or something.

My goal is to have the two browsers working independently without waiting for each other.

I searched a lot online but found so little documentation and no clear case about my situation.

I hope someone can help. The main question is how to have two browsers working independently at the same time using Laravel Dusk.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test with parallel clicks?

Comment: I want to test transactions happening at almost the same time. If there is only one product, and there are two customers clicking purchase simultaneously I need to be sure that the system will give the product to one of them, and will tell the other the product became out of stock. I already coded the logic to assure that .. but can't test it yet!

Comment: You can't (reliably) test transactions with a browser test. Even if both browsers run in parallel, there are so many layers between browser and database with varying execution times. In most cases, one of the transactions will end before the other one starts.

Comment: Yes, I started to be convinced about that. But I am searching for the closest I can get, even though that doesn't seem useful if I really understood the layers you are talking about .. in the process.  I have a tester behind me that thinks he really can test the function from test automation programs and tricks! I wanted to beat that in code so I am using laravel dusk.

Comment: Testing parallel transactions is not trivial. Dusk is not the right choice for it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir But still would like to know if there is a parallel option that Dusk can provide which makes two browsers work independently without waiting for each other! that is the problem now!

Comment: I think you would need 2 instances of dusk running at the same time.  to do that, you'd probably want a parent script that runs exec() to start each of the two instances.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Multiple Browsers

```
$this->browse(function ($first, $second) {

$first->loginAs(User::find(1))
      ->visit('/home')
      ->waitForText('Message');

$second->loginAs(User::find(2))
       ->visit('/home')
       ->waitForText('Message')
       ->type('message', 'Hey Taylor')
       ->press('Send');

$first->waitForText('Hey Taylor')
      ->assertSee('Jeffrey Way');

});
```

Comment: Here the $second login and visit has to wait for the $first to finish visiting and waiting for text `'Message'`. The question is can Dusk make the two browsers work independently without waiting for each other?!